# How to group every two elements in a Map?

Tags: sql, performance, logic

I have a `Map<Integer,String>`, now I want to loop through this map and group every two values with parenthesis, like `(va1 AND val2) AND (val3 AND val4)` so on. I need to form a query like this.

eg- Lets say my map contains

```
Country (Key)   'United States' 'Japan' 'France'    'England'   'India'
Currency (Value)    'Dollar'    'Yen'   'Euro'  'Pound' 'Rupee'
```

Now I want to group like

```
(United States = 'Dollar' AND Japan='Yen') AND(France = 'Euro' AND England='Pound') ...
```

Comment: Give sample data and expected result

Comment: @Mansoor updated post

Comment: what you try and your query

Comment: what is the programming language you are using? your question is more related to how to construct a sql query by using the map and not really related to sql itself. ideally just do a for / foreach over the map to construct your query